# NAD83 metes + bounds differ from NAD27 using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cogo

I am in the process of digtizing easements in ArcMap and I am trying to figure out if I have a projection issue. Almost all of the source documents have plats with X/Y coordinates and legal descriptions for every easement. All of these are in NAD83, but the toolset I am using forces me to create all data in NAD27.

When I am creating these easements, I usually will just take the provided X/Y coordinates for the POB (point of beginning), convert them to NAD27 using [NCAT](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/), and enter the metes + bounds exactly as they are described in the source documents, ultimately ending up with a line which I will then buffer based on the easement size. That buffer is then clipped against a polygon layer of section lines, so it doesn't encroach on an area outside of the legal description.

A lot of times, these will look slightly off compared to how they look in the plat - which I assumed was a projection issue.

Do you think the metes + bounds that are in NAD83 would be different than those in NAD27 and, if so, is there a way to convert them, or will I just have to convert each X/Y coordinate for every single point on the line and connect them manually?

This image shows what I am talking about:
[image: Sample of Issues]

All of these easements (green lines) should be contained entirely within SEC 33. The red point in the center is the point of reference for all of the green dots which are the points of beginning for each line. Instead of just putting in the X/Y coordinates for the points of beginning for each line, I tried using the metes + bounds to determine it and map each easement from there.

Do you think that the descriptions being in NAD83 and putting them in to NAD27 is throwing them off that much?

The easiest option would be to simply just use the COGO tools and there would be no issue, but unfortunately my company only provides us with the basic license and a set of horrible digitizing tools.

Comment: The COGO tools should be available at any license level.  There are also the distance, direction and other right click options when digitizing.  I would do all the work in the native projection of the easement descriptions, then convert each to NAD 27 when you are done, using the appropriate transformation.  Does the following help? https://gisobsessed.blogspot.com/2010/03/cogo-made-easy-in-arcgis-desktop.html